Horizontal axis title on top after coord_flip
I've been trying for a while now to put the horizontal axis title on top of the chart after using coord_flip() in ggplot2, but without any success.
I know I could:

Set scale_y_continuous (position = "right")
Set theme (axis.title.x.top = element_text (face = "bold")) # I guess any format would do here, right?

But then:

The whole axis would go to the top, and I want only the axis title there
It doesn't work, for some reason


CODE
example <- iris |> 

ggplot             (aes (x = reorder (Species, Petal.Width), y = Petal.Width))                          +    
geom_bar           (stat = "identity", fill = "gray60")                                                 +
geom_hline         (yintercept = 100 / nrow (iris), linetype = "dashed", color = "firebrick", size = 1) +
scale_y_continuous (limits = c(0, 15), breaks = seq (0, 15, 2.5), expand = c(0, 0))                     +
coord_flip         ()                                                                                   +

labs (x = "", y = "Horizontal axis title") +

theme (axis.title       = element_text (family = "MS", face = "bold", size = 18, color = "black"),
       axis.text        = element_text (family = "TNR", face = "plain", size = 16, color = "black"),
       axis.text.x      = element_text (angle = 45),
       panel.background = element_rect (fill = NA),
       panel.grid.major = element_line (color = "gray90"),
       panel.grid.minor = element_line (color = "gray90"),
       plot.margin      = margin       (t = 20, r = 20, b = 5, l = 5)) +

windows (); example


I'd defer to @stefan's solution for splitting up the axis title and the breaks; that is simplest with a duplicate axis.
I would add, though, that most cases to use coord_flip() were eliminated with ggplot2 3.3.0 in 2020. (Though occasionally you may need to add the orientation parameter if the aesthetics don't make it clear).
Then we can do:
iris |> 
  ggplot(aes(y = reorder (Species, Petal.Width), x = Petal.Width))  +    
  geom_col(fill = "gray60") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 100 / nrow (iris), linetype = "dashed", 
             color = "firebrick", size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 15), breaks = seq (0, 15, 2.5), 
                      expand = c(0, 0), name = NULL,
                      sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = NULL, name = "Horizontal axis title")) +
  labs(y = NULL) # avoids even having a space for the axis title



Very nice !!! Thank you so much for your help !!! It worked perfectly!!!

One option would be to use a secondary axis for which you remove the axis text and ticks using e.g. breaks=NULL and getting rid of the primary axis title:
library(ggplot2)

iris |>
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Species, Petal.Width), y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "gray60") +
  geom_hline(
    yintercept = 100 / nrow(iris), linetype = "dashed",
    color = "firebrick", size = 1
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 15), breaks = seq(0, 15, 2.5), expand = c(0, 0),
    sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = NULL, name = "Horizontal axis title")
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "", y = NULL) +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 18, color = "black"),
    axis.text = element_text(face = "plain", size = 16, color = "black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray90"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "gray90"),
    plot.margin = margin(t = 20, r = 20, b = 5, l = 5)
  )
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> Warning: Removed 82 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_bar()`).


